# How to use method from promise on condition?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, lazy-loading

I lazy-loaded this module `const getMockedModule = () => import("z-mock-client")` and want use `mockedClient` method from this module:

```
const mockedClient = () => createMockedClient({
    mocks,
    typeDefs,
})

export {
    mockedClient
}
```

And on this condition, I use this var

```js
const getCat = () => import("z-mock-client")
const mocked = getCat().then(prop => prop.mockedClient())
const apolloProvider = new VueApollo({
    defaultClient: MOCKED_UI ? mocked : v2,
    clients: {
        v2: MOCKED_UI ? mocked : v2
    }
})
```

But on the result of mocked var, I got

```
Promise {<pending>}
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: ApolloClient
```

how to get promise value like a result of `const mocked`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use condition code after promise returns. Like so:

```js
const getCat = () => import("z-mock-client")
const mocked = getCat().then((prop) => {
  prop.mockedClient()
  const apolloProvider = new VueApollo({
    defaultClient: MOCKED_UI ? mocked : v2,
    clients: {
        v2: MOCKED_UI ? mocked : v2
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: there no sense for me, because I load getCat module on MOCKED_UI flag condition, for the rule: insert or not insert getCat module in js bundle